# How to Handle Push Notifications that are not Opened (iOS, Swift)

Tags: ios, swift, push-notification

So I am running a Swift application and using `Parse` to handle my push notifications. So far everything is working as expected.

I am sending `JSON` objects through the push notifications and updating a local array from the data received. I am handling the data through the `application: didReceiveRemoteNotification` and sending a dictionary through `userInfo`.

This works perfectly when the app is open in the foreground. It also works great when the app is in the background and the user opens the Push Notification when it is displayed in the banner.

The JSON object is handled according to the `application: didReceiveRemoteNotification` code.

However, when the user does not open the notification, `application: didReceiveRemoteNotification` does not get run and my local array does not get updated.

How do I make sure every time a notification is sent the JSON object gets handled and updates my local array accordingly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is generally incorrect approach, you should not rely on push notifications, user may switch them off or due to some reasons they may not be delivered. Instead you should get new data always from your server. Read from the [Apple Push Notification Service Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/Chapters/ApplePushService.html):

> **Important**: Delivery of notifications is a “best effort”, not guaranteed. It is not intended to deliver data to your app, only to notify the user that there is new data available

Comment: Thanks for the information! I will now be updating my local data through the server... Gonna need a large coffee for this one!

Comment: Hi, I know this is a bit late, but I've been using Parse a lot too, and Parse has very powerful online and offline database functionalities that you can use to make your life easier if you want to do server side jobs.

Answer (score 4):

You can not get get response or JSON object from Notification until User click on it and either `didReceiveRemoteNotification` or `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` method get invoke.

From ios8, you can set interactive notification, which is useful to interact direct from notification, without opening application in foreground.

[HERE](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=e7cTZ4Tp25I) it the tutorial for interactive Notification.

May this help you.

Comment: This link to nrj.io not working. It says "Country not allowed". So looks like we have some 'allowed' countries, and some are not. As if iOS developers choose where to be born. :)

Comment: Hey @Argus, Thanks for highlighting, Updated more standard and details link for the same. By the way, iOS developers born anywhere have worldwide rights to access help. Happy to help.

Answer (score 0):

```
application:didReceiveRemoteNotification:fetchCompletionHandler:
```

this method will call even if user will not tap or interact with notification.

When a remote notification arrives, the system calls the 
`application:didReceiveRemoteNotification:fetchCompletionHandler:`
 method. Notifications usually signal the availability of new information. In your app delegate method, you might begin downloading new data from a server so that you can update your app’s data structures. You might also use the notification to update your user interface.
-Apple Inc.

The state of app must be in `UIApplicationStateActive` or `UIApplicationStateBackground`.

You can not do anything if state of application is `UIApplicationStateInactive`.

Comment: didReceiveRemoteNotification call even if user will not tap or interact with notification only if push contains <content_available: "true">